# React app is making multiple fetch calls and one of the fetch calls is an Array of urls. I am trying to use Promise.all but receiving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the memory game project from TOP and am trying to auto populate the memory game with calling the Formula 1 Ergast API. Upon doing this I am having to make multiple fetch calls - the first fetch call works retrieving the driver information with a link to the their wikipedia page. I then try to make a second Fetch API call to retrieve all the Driver images on the wikipedia page through another query.

I am currently stuck on how to Promise.all multiple URLs and get the new drivers to update the driver data objects with the image URL.

For example,

Here is the Driver Information fetch:

```
const driverYear = useRef();
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);
  const getDrivers = async (year) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + "/drivers.json"
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    let driverInfo = [];
    data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers.map((driver) => {
      driverInfo.push({
        id: driver.code,
        firstName: driver.givenName,
        lastName: driver.familyName,
        wikipedia: driver.url,
        image: null,
      });
    });
    setDrivers(driverInfo);
    getDriversImgs(); // THIS IS A CALL TO THE SECOND FETCH
  };
```

Here is how my data looks after i setState with an array of newly created objects. This is from console.

```
0:
firstName: "Alexander"
id: "ALB"
image: null
lastName: "Albon"
wikipedia: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Albon"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
firstName: "Fernando"
id: "ALO"
image: null
lastName: "Alonso"
wikipedia: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Alonso"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is the part I have an issue with:

```
  const getDriversImgs = async () => {
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      drivers.map((driver) => {
        let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
        let wiki_url =
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" +
          wikiPageName +
          "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
        return fetch(wiki_url);
      })
    );
    const jsons = await Promise.all(responses.map((r) => r.json()));
    console.log(jsons);
};
```

Json data I should be receiving from the queries looks like this:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"normalized":[{"from":"Mick_Schumacher","to":"Mick Schumacher"}],"pages":{"7772370":{"pageid":7772370,"ns":0,"title":"Mick Schumacher","thumbnail":{"source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Mick_Schumacher_-_2019202181015_2019-07-21_Champions_for_Charity_-_1500_-_B70I1535.jpg/333px-Mick_Schumacher_-_2019202181015_2019-07-21_Champions_for_Charity_-_1500_-_B70I1535.jpg","width":333,"height":500},"pageimage":"Mick_Schumacher_-_2019202181015_2019-07-21_Champions_for_Charity_-_1500_-_B70I1535.jpg"}}}}
```

I have about 4 iterations of this but the ultimate goal is to fetch the drivers Wikipedia page image url and then update the Driver object Image with the new image. For some reason the Promise.all is getting rejected and I think it is because I have been writing it wrong.

Currently I am receiving this:

```
localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Alexander_Albon&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**Note** The Fetch at above when I click on the link return me the JSON file

Could someone give me some direction on how to make multiple fetch calls of urls and get them to return into an array. I know I haven't put in try catch yet but I was hoping to get some functionality first before failing

**Extra**
Here is the whole component if you are curious. Once I complete this I will put in a try/catch handler for the fetches and will be breaking this out into other components. I wanted to first see if I could get this functional before I proceeded with anything else.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, useRef } from "react";

const Header = () => {
  const driverYear = useRef();
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);
  const getDrivers = async (year) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + "/drivers.json"
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    let driverInfo = [];
    data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers.map((driver) => {
      driverInfo.push({
        id: driver.code,
        firstName: driver.givenName,
        lastName: driver.familyName,
        wikipedia: driver.url,
        image: null,
      });
    });
    setDrivers(driverInfo);
    getDriversImgs();
  };

  async function getDriversImgs() {
    console.log("working");
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      drivers.map((driver) => {
        let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
        let wiki_url =
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" +
          wikiPageName +
          "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
        return fetch(wiki_url);
      })
    );
    console.log("here are the responses", responses);
    const jsons = await Promise.all(responses.map((r) => r.json()));
    console.log(jsons);

    // const requests = Promise.all(
    //   drivers.map(async (driver) => {
    //     let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1);
    //     let wiki_url =
    //       "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" +
    //       wikiPageName +
    //       "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
    //     return await fetch(wiki_url)
    //   })
    // );

    // const requests = drivers.map((driver) => {
    //   let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1);
    //   let wiki_url =
    //     "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" +
    //     wikiPageName +
    //     "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
    //   return fetch(wiki_url);
    // });
    // const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
    // const promises = responses.map((response) => response.json());
    // return await Promise.all(promises);

    //     Promise.all(
    //       drivers.map(async (driver) => {
    //         let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
    //         let wiki_url =
    //           "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" +
    //           wikiPageName +
    //           "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
    //         console.log(wiki_url);
    //         const response = await fetch(wiki_url);
    //         const imgUrl = await response.json();
    //         driver.image = imgUrl;
    //         console.log(imgUrl);
    //       })
    //     );
    //     console.log("Here is new driver data");
  }

  const driverYearHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const year = driverYear.current.value;
    getDrivers(year);
  };
  return (
    <header>
      <form onSubmit={driverYearHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="year">Enter Year:</label>
        <input type="text" id="year" ref={driverYear} />
        <button>Get Drivers</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {drivers.map((driver) => (
          <li key={driver.id}>{driver.firstName + " " + driver.lastName}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Please check API docs. It says one have to add origin parameter: "When accessing the API using a cross-domain AJAX request (CORS), set this to the originating domain. This must be included in any pre-flight request, and therefore must be part of the request URI (not the POST body)."
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: @ArtBauer awesome thank you I read up on it and was able to validate a small bug in my code when I get the wikiPageName I .split.slice it and forgot to convert it to a string. So now I am having error free code I am just receiving null